# Definition for the set of Real Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could the set of Real Numbers be defined as \begin{array}{l}
\mathbb{R} \equiv \mathbb{Q} \cup \{ x\neq \frac{a}{b} :a\wedge b\in \mathbb{Q} \}
\end{array} ? Why or why not?

Comment: How do you assert that the set $\{x\ne \frac{a}{b}:a\land b\in \mathbb{Q}\}\ne\emptyset$?

Comment: Also take some time to read [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03467).

Comment: the only definition you should learn on $\mathbb{R}$ is that it contains the rationnals, and also the non rationnals limits of (converging) sequences of rationnal numbers. please also note that every rationnals are definissable, while only the irrationnals being the limit of some  definissable sequence of rationnals numbers are definissable.

Comment: No, it cannot, because $0\in\mathbb{Q}$, and so $b=0\implies\frac{a}{b}\not\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5):

The set of cats is not a rational number. So $x$ could be the set of cats. That's probably not a real number.

In slightly more serious terms, where do these $x$ belong? You need a set to draw these from.

Read about dedekind cuts for one approach that derives the reals from subsets of rationals. Cauchy's completeness  argument defines them uses sequences of rationals. These are the classical approaches. The point is we build them from things we know, rather than just say what they are not.

Comment: Hah I was typing something similar to this. $+1$

Comment: Well I never had any higher education and almost everything I know is what I have taught myself, thank you anyway.

Comment: With the intricate problem that cats, themselves, are *not* mathematical objects, whereas sets can only have mathematical objects as elements.

Answer (score 2):

Context is everything.

What is the set $\{x\mid x\neq 0\}$? If you are working *in* $\Bbb Q$ the set is different from the set you obtain if you work in $\Bbb R$ or in $\Bbb Z$ or in $\Bbb C$.

If you are working inside "the mathematical universe", and you can "access" every mathematical object, then this is not a set anymore, since the mathematical universe is not a set; and moreover the meaning of the symbol $0$ is now unclear.

The same goes in your question. What is the context for $x$ in $x\neq\frac ab$? Is $x$ already a real number? Is $x$ just an arbitrary mathematical object? It's not clear at all. Especially since if you want to *define* the real numbers then they cannot be the context in which you're working in. The whole idea of defining something is to "refine the given context".

Finally, there is another very mild issue as to whether or not $\Bbb Q\subseteq\Bbb R$, or is there just "a canonical copy of $\Bbb Q$ inside $\Bbb R$". And this will affect the answer as to $\Bbb R$ is equal to that union or not. But let's ignore that for now.

The real problem is that unless you already assume that $x$ is a real number, there's no way you can claim that this is a good definition for $\Bbb R$; but if $x$ is already a real number, you already had to define $\Bbb R$.